# I need a help to get data from a table which has id,serialnumber,process(prcs) and result

Tags: sql-server

The query able to get the recent failed process(prcs) of that serialnumber,if the recent process(prcs) is Pass, it will not show. But my problem is if the Last process is PASS,do not show the serial number.Now im able to get the recent Failed process but i want to ignore it if the last process is pass.Thank you

The Query i tried-:

```
SELECT tt.id,tt.serialnumber,tt.prcs,tt.result
FROM tblTest tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT serialnumber,prcs MAX(id) AS MaxID
    FROM tblTest 
    GROUP BY  serialnumber,prcs) groupedtt 
ON tt.prcs = groupedtt.prcs AND tt.id = groupedtt.MaxID
WHERE result='FAIL' AND tt.sn='A01'  
ORDER by serialnumber
```

[image: IF last process PASS,dont show the serialnumber]

[image: If last process fail, show process(5th and LastProcess).Process 4th wont show because the process is passed after it failed(My query able to counter this)]

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. Please consider reading the following articles: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_ and _[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) (Meta DBA.SE)_. Currently your question doesn't contain enough information and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). E.g., adding the expected results to your question would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, 
                     serialnumber, 
                     prcs, 
                     result, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY serialnumber 
                                        ORDER BY id DESC) rn
              FROM tblTest )
SELECT id, serialnumber, prcs, result
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
  AND result = 'FAIL'
```

> if lastprocess and 5th process fail, should show both

Try:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tblTest t1
WHERE t1.result = 'FAIL'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM tblTest t2
                   WHERE t1.serialnumber = t2.serialnumber 
                     AND t1.id < t2.id
                     AND t2.result != 'FAIL' )
```

Comment: this query only able to get if lastprocess is failed..if lastprocess and 5th process fail, should show both(refer 2nd pic)

Comment: @KuHan You have not shown what answer is required. So I did as I understood.

Comment: Thanks for your help,i appreciate it . Sorry if i was question is confusing, i am a beginner

Comment: @KuHan One question - one task, please...

Comment: There is also another condition where if a process failed twice, get the lastest record by MAX(id)